# Bigquery: UNNEST repeated vs flatten table performance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using nested tables with sturct record type with array of fields.
On top of it I am using a view, but to reference a particular fied(s) in view I need to unnest the table first, which again makes the result fatten.

So is it wise to already store a data into flatten format or use nested table and use unnest in view? with both the ways i am getting same output.

Comment: There is no issue unnesting in views.  If you data fits naturally into a nested format, then use that.

Comment: Does it affect performance to do this every time you read?

Comment: testing on performance, stay tuned

Comment: Was the results similar in both scenarios? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'll store data in the flatten format, then flatten table's size will be larger compared to the original table due to repetition of data in columns which are not repeated in the original table. Larger table's size will result in higher costs for both storage and queries.

But it highly depends on the size of that non-repeated columns and the specific queries you'll use.

You can try both variants and see which one will process less GB when queried with your specific queries. Also take a look at the `Execution details`(Query plan).

Comment: Yes, that's one thing but as Bigquery provides cheaper rates for storage I am not much worried about that,  looking from more of which is a better way to do it, I am also checking the performance and bytes processed. will get back with my observations